# Find words that are unique for 1 set out of 3 C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have 3 sets containing words.

```
a: car, boat, table, ball

b: car, goat, helicopter

c: square, car, goat, boat
```

I need to create a vector or set with words that are contained ONLY in set a.

So the answer would be:

```
result: table, ball
```

I tried to make it using set_difference and set_intersection but no luck so far. Can you suggest me something?

I tried

```
set_difference(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), res.begin()); 
set_difference(res.begin(), res.end(), c.begin(), c.end(), res.begin());
```

But the result is empty

Comment: `std::set_difference` is the standard tool for this Job.  Can you show your code using it and we can help you ti fix it?

Comment: Did you sort your arrays before using `std::set_difference`?

Comment: actually I can't understand how do I put 3 sets instead of 2 into ```std::set_difference```

Comment: You don't.  you run difference against `a` and `b` creating output `d`.  and then you run difference against `d` and `c` creating your result set.

Comment: I tried ```set_difference(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), res.begin());
    set_difference(res.begin(), res.end(), c.begin(), c.end(), res.begin()); ``` But the result is empty

Comment: The second line is wrong. You are modifying `res` while iterating over it. You should use a `final_res` variable to store the second result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

> ```
> set_difference(res.begin(), res.end(), c.begin(), c.end(), res.begin());
> //             ^            ^                              ^
> ```

You iterate over `res` and write the result in the same set. You need another set to store the result.

A solution would be:

```
std::set<std::string> a {"car", "boat", "table", "ball"};
std::set<std::string> b {"car", "goat", "helicopter"};
std::set<std::string> c {"square", "car", "goat", "boat"};

std::set<std::string> tmp;
std::set<std::string> res;

// Difference between a and b --> stored in tmp
std::set_difference(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::inserter(tmp, tmp.begin()));

// Difference between tmp and c --> stored in res
std::set_difference(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), c.begin(), c.end(), std::inserter(res, res.begin()));

for(const std::string & s : res)
    std::cout << s << '\n';
```

Output:

> ball
>   table

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/pEP2t9)

---

**Note:** If we look at the documentation of [`std::set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference), we can see:

> Copies the elements from the sorted range [first1, last1) which are not found in the sorted range [first2, last2) to the range beginning at d_first.
>
> The resulting range is also sorted. **Equivalent elements are treated individually, that is, if some element is found m times in [first1, last1) and n times in [first2, last2), it will be copied to d_first exactly std::max(m-n, 0) times.** The resulting range cannot overlap with either of the input ranges.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So if you want to use another container that does not guarantee the uniqueness of its elements (for example `std::vector`), you need to ensure that each element does not appear several times in your container by yourself.

---

**Note 2:** If you don't want to bother with the `tmp` set (which is useless after getting the `res` set), you can put it inside a bloc so that it will be destroyed afterwards:

```
std::set<std::string> res;

{
    std::set<std::string> tmp;
    std::set_difference(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::inserter(tmp, tmp.begin()));
    std::set_difference(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), c.begin(), c.end(), std::inserter(res, res.begin()));
} // tmp destroyed here
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/ToiiZf)

Answer (score 0):

Without sharing your code, we can only guess as to what your code is doing wrong.

Here's what I did.  I wrapped the difference logic in a helper `operator-`.  I used `std::unordered_set` intentionally, because they can't be used directly in `std::set_difference`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::inserter;
using std::ostream;
using std::set_difference;
using std::sort;
using std::string;
using std::unordered_set;
using std::vector;

namespace {

unordered_set<string> operator-(unordered_set<string> const& minuend, unordered_set<string> const& subtrahend) {
    vector<string> m(minuend.begin(), minuend.end());
    vector<string> s(subtrahend.begin(), subtrahend.end());
    sort(m.begin(), m.end());
    sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    unordered_set<string> diff;
    set_difference(m.begin(), m.end(), s.begin(), s.end(), inserter(diff, diff.begin()));
    return diff;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, unordered_set<string> const& container) {
    char const* sep = " ";
    out << "{";

    for (auto const& s : container) {
        out << sep << "\"" << s << "\"";
        sep = ", ";
    }
    out << " }";
    return out;
}

}

int main() {
    auto a = unordered_set<string>{ "car", "boat", "table", "ball" };
    auto b = unordered_set<string>{ "car", "goat", "helicopter" };
    auto c = unordered_set<string>{ "square", "car", "goat", "boat" };
    auto d = a - b - c;
    cout << d << "\n";
}
```

**UPDATE** answering Fareanor's questions

*Why do you use std::unordered_set (instead of std::set)?*

I chose the unordered_set to demonstrate that the set_difference required a sorted container.  The unordered_set lacks that feature.

And the original poster, in the original unedited question, did not provide the details of what kind of container was being used.

*Why do you convert it into a std::vector that will need to be sorted (instead of converting into std::set)?*

A vector is a very efficient container, since the elements in it have a locality, and therefore good cache.  It is my go-to container.

A set has a lot more memory allocations because it is a mesh of nodes, and lacks the locality.

The string object being contained may lack the locality anyway, since it is basically a smart pointer to a character array.  But because of small string optimization (SSO) and these are small strings, it won't also be allocating off the heap.

In the original poster's scenario, there are only a few items in each of the container, so the efficiency concerns are negligible.  But worth thinking about, if the problem domain was scaled up.

*I think you should have used std::set (without any clarification from the OP at least) and if the user got a std::unordered_set instead, it is up to him to convert it to a proper std::set and then call your `operator-()`.*

That is a viable option.  Lacking the context at the time, I considered this a "worse case scenario" because the unordered_set container does not fulfill the requirement of the set_difference algorithm.

Comment: I like your idea, it is very elegant. However there are few things that I don't understand: Why do you use `std::unordered_set` (instead of `std::set`) ? Why do you convert it into a `std::vector` that will need to be sorted (instead of converting into `std::set`) ? I think you should have used `std::set` (without any clarification from the OP at least) and if the user got a `std::unordered_set` instead, it is up to him to convert it to a proper `std::set` and then call your `operator-()`.